# Set the default ExecutionContext for Actor System in Java

Tags: java, akka

I want to pass the reference of a ExecutorService object in Java as a default dispatcher/executionContext while creating Actor System. Is there a way to do that rather than reading the dispatcher properties from config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ActorSystem` factory method [`create`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#create-java.lang.String-com.typesafe.config.Config-java.lang.ClassLoader-scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext-) that takes an `ExecutionContext` as an argument. Here are the method signature and the Javadoc (emphasis mine):

```
public static ActorSystem create(java.lang.String name,
                                 com.typesafe.config.Config config,
                                 java.lang.ClassLoader classLoader,
                                 scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext defaultExecutionContext)
```

> Creates a new ActorSystem with the specified name, the specified Config, the specified ClassLoader, and the specified ExecutionContext. **The ExecutionContext will be used as the default executor inside this ActorSystem**. If `null` is passed in for the Config, ClassLoader and/or ExecutionContext parameters, the respective default value will be used. If no Config is given, the default reference config will be obtained from the ClassLoader. If no ClassLoader is given, it obtains the current ClassLoader by first inspecting the current threads' getContextClassLoader, then tries to walk the stack to find the callers class loader, then falls back to the ClassLoader associated with the ActorSystem class. If no ExecutionContext is given, the system will fallback to the executor configured under "akka.actor.default-dispatcher.default-executor.fallback". Note that the given ExecutionContext will be used by all dispatchers that have been configured with executor = "default-executor", including those that have not defined the executor setting and thereby fallback to the default of "default-dispatcher.executor".

For example:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext;

final ExecutionContext ec = ...

ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem", null, null, ec);
```

Comment: It takes scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext as argument but what I have is java.concurrent.ExecutorService. Is there a way to switch between the two.